# Laravel transactions with logic

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, laravel-6

I try to have logic in my transaction, but it just keeps adding the data to the database and I don't know what's going wrong...

The code I currently have:

```
public function addQuote($customer_id, Request $request)
{
    //try catch, since there can be errors in it
    DB::transaction(function() use ($customer_id, $request) {
        try {

            // Make a project for a quote, but not a main project, to not interfere with other existing projects
            $quote_project = QuoteProject::create([
                'projectnumber' => $request->project_number,
                'name' => $request->project_name,
                'address' => $request->project_address,
                'zipcode' => $request->project_zipcode,
                'city' => $request->project_city,
                'country' => $request->project_country ?? 'BE',
                'customer_id' => $customer_id,
            ]);

            // Make a quote
            $quote = Quote::create([
                'status_id' => 1, // assign pending status
                'reference' => $request->reference,
                'number' => rand(),
                'department_id' => $request->department,
                'project_id' => $quote_project->id, // Created project id
                'location_id' => ($request->location === 0) ? null : $request->location, // location -> can be 0 as value, if so, leave empty
                'customer_id' => $customer_id,
                'contact_id' => $request->contact_id,
                'layout_id' => $request->layout_id,
                'seller_id' => $request->seller_id,
                'date_from' => Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->date_from)->format('Y-m-d'),
                'date_till' => Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->date_till)->format('Y-m-d'),
                'document_number' => $request->document_number,
                'customer_number' => $request->customer_number,
                'vat_type_id' => $request->vat_type_id,
                'vat_tariff_id' => $request->vat_tariff_id,
            ]);

            $quote->conditions()->attach($request->payment_conditions);

            if (isset($request->head_group)) {
                // set a global sync data variable
                $sync_data = [];
                // Loop over all the head groups
                foreach ($request->head_group as $key => $head_group) {
                    // create or update head group
                    $created_head_group = ArticleGroup::updateOrCreate([
                        'quote_id' => $quote->id,
                        'name' => $head_group ?? ''
                    ], [
                        'comment' => $request->head_group_comment[$key] ?? '',
                        'head_group' => 1,
                        'parent_group' => null,
                        'bold' => filter_var($request->bold_head[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ?? false,
                        'italic' => filter_var($request->italic_head[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ?? false,
                        'underline' => filter_var($request->underline_head[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ?? false,
                        'color' => str_replace('#', '', $request->color_head[$key]) ?? null
                    ]);
                    // Loop over the sub groups in a main group
                    foreach ($request->sub_group[$key] as $s_key => $sub_group) {
                        // Create or update a subgroup
                        $created_sub_group = ArticleGroup::updateOrCreate([
                            'quote_id' => $quote->id,
                            'name' => $sub_group ?? ''
                        ], [
                            'comment' => $request->sub_group_comment[$key][$s_key] ?? '',
                            'head_group' => 0,
                            'parent_group' => $created_head_group->id,
                            'bold' => filter_var($request->bold_sub[$key][$s_key], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ?? false,
                            'italic' => filter_var($request->italic_sub[$key][$s_key], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ?? false,
                            'underline' => filter_var($request->underline_sub[$key][$s_key], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ?? false,
                            'color' => str_replace('#', '', $request->color_sub[$key][$s_key]) ?? null
                        ]);
                        // Loop over the articles in the subgroup
                        foreach ($request->articles[$key][$s_key] as $a_key => $article_id) {
                            if (isset($request->articles[$key][$s_key])) {
                                $id = explode('-', $article_id);
                                $sync_data[$id[0]] = [
                                    'name' => $request->custom_article_name[$key][$s_key][$a_key],
                                    'quantity' => $request->quantity[$key][$s_key][$a_key],
                                    'thickness' => $request->thickness[$key][$s_key][$a_key],
                                    'price' => $request->article_price[$key][$s_key][$a_key],
                                    'description' => $request->description[$key][$s_key][$a_key],
                                    'group_id' => $created_sub_group->id
                                ];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $quote->articles()->sync($sync_data);   // sync the articles
            }

            // return data for ajax call, since the wizard works via an ajax call submit
            return url('customers/' . $customer_id . '/quotations/');
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }
```

);
}

If someone could explain me what I'm doing wrong here, that would be a really great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works. If inside `DB::transaction` exception is thrown then transaction is rolled back automatically. However in your implementation exception is not thrown because you catch it inside transaction and just try to return error response (what by the way won't work because you miss return in `DB::transaction(function() use ($customer_id, $request) {` line).

The easiest way to solve is to catch exception not inside `DB::transaction` but outside of it - then it will behave as you expected, transaction will be rolled back.

Alternative solution in some cases it not using `DB::transaction` but instead using manual:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
DB::rollBack();
DB::commit();
```

as described in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#database-transactions).